# Using Waze map tiles with Leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, tiles, waze

I came across this [Map Comparisons](http://mc.bbbike.org/mc/?lon=13.368594&lat=52.459748&zoom=10&num=2&mt0=osm-no-labels&mt1=mapnik&marker=) where they have used Waze map tiles. I searched around and couldn't find any official documentation for using Waze tiles in leaflet. I couldn't even find their privacy policy that concerns with usage of tiles. I'm retrieving tiles from `http://livemap-tiles4.waze.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` in leafletjs. Waze client apps are open source; so does it mean I can use waze tiles without concerning their policy?

Comment: [here are their TOS](https://www.waze.com/legal/tos).

Comment: What do you mean by "Using waze tiles in OSM"? OpenStreetMap is a database of geographic information, there isn't a way to use map tiles in it. If you mean tracing data from waze tiles into OpenStreetMap that is almost certainly a violation of there TOS.

Comment: My bad. I mean using Waze tiles instead of OSM tiles in leaflet.

Comment: I can't find anything about this their TOS. So is it allowed or not?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to get permission to use those tiles.  Though some of the software implementations are open source (and GPL) the data itself is not.  Since Waze has its own source for maps, these maps and the user-driven data fall into its definition of 'content.'

From the terms of service (emphasis mine):

(from copyright section)

> The Software license granted to you in these Terms ***does not extend to or include a license to use the maps*** displayed on the Software or any mark, indicator, logo or notation embedded in the maps that are displayed on the Software. You may not copy or print more than one copy of any data or material appearing on the Site.

(from rights in content section)

> You may not, whether yourself or through any other means or person : (i) copy, modify, adapt, translate, reverse engineer, decompile, or disassemble any portion of the Content included in the Service and/or Site, ***or in any way or publicly display, perform, or distribute them; (ii) make any use of the Content on any other website or networked computer environment for any purpose***, or replicate or copy the Content without Waze’s prior written consent; (iii) create a ***browser or border environment around the Content*** (e.g. no frames or inline linking);

The Map Comparisons link you provided mentions "All map tiles copyrighted by their providers!" but I believe they are actually breaking the Waze terms of service.